# I need to translate the functionality from TensorFlow's clip_by_norm to Pytorch and I am confused

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, pytorch

Hello StackOverflow community :),
I need to utilize the functionality of https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_norm in the axis 1, for a two dimensional matrix in Pytorch, but I am confused on how to do it, as I have not found the equivalent operation in .
Effectively, I need to compute the l2 norm in the across the second dimension of my tensor, which I am already doing with `l2_norm = torch.linalg.norm(tensor,dim=1,keepdim=True)` and then I need to compare against a cutoff which I compute as `full_size_vals = torch.full_like(l2_norm,cutoff_value)`.
Afterwards I obtain a boolean tensor with the rows I need to update with `boolean_tensor = l2_norm > full_size_vals` and here is where I am stuck. To each of the true boolean rows I have to apply the following function:

```
updated_row = row * cutoff_value / l2norm(row)
```

And then collect back the updated rows back to the original matrix.
How do I do this?
Thanks a lot :)